# Why the outcomes 0?

Tags: c

I am begginer and im trying to my homework.I don't know why the outcomes 0.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}Vector;
void print_vector(Vector vector);
Vector enterVector();
int main()
{
    Vector v1;
    printf("\nEnter vector v1:\n");
    v1 = enterVector();
    print_vector(v1);
    return 0;
}
void print_vector(Vector vector)
{
    printf("x=%.2f, y=%.2f, z=%.2f\n",&vector.x,&vector.y,&vector.z);
}
Vector enterVector(){
    Vector vector;
    printf("x-axis="); 
    scanf("%f",&vector.x);
    printf("y-axis="); 
    scanf("%f",&vector.y);
    printf("z-axis="); 
    scanf("%f",&vector.z);
    return vector;
}
```

Here is an example output:

```
Enter vector v1:
x-axis=1
y-axis=2
z-axis=3
x=0.00, y=0.00, z=0.00
```

Comment: Printf's arguments should be the actual values, not pointers. In modern C++ you should use `std::cin` and `std::cout` instead.

Comment: Remove the `&`s from `printf()`.

Comment: I guess that what you see is undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void print_vector(Vector vector)
{
    printf("x=%.2f, y=%.2f, z=%.2f\n", vector.x, vector.y, vector.z);
}
```

You should not get the address of the pointers, get the values directly instead.

> **Example Output**

```
Enter vector v1:
x-axis=1
y-axis=2
z-axis=3
x=1.00, y=2.00, z=3.00
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

When passing arguments to `printf`, you should pass the actual values, not the address of those values:

```
printf("x=%.2f, y=%.2f, z=%.2f\n",vector.x,vector.y,vector.z);
```